Manhua/manhwa where the main character goes to a dungeon/rift break and finds a wolf commander which can speak and is walking on two feet
The main character (MC) goes to a dungeon / rift break and finds a wolf commander which can speak and is walking on two feet. They fight, then the boss realizes the MC is too powerful, causing it to try and escape back into the rift, but the MC says "You're an animal. Run on all fours."
That's what I remember. Also, the party inside the rift/dungeon have a shield protecting them for the time being. Also, there's an enemy within them.
This is a different manhua / manhwa i think cant really remember:

The MC has dark abilities.
The MC is called to go to a sea rift / dungeon.
A girl in the manhua looks for the MC to help with her powers (she's an S-rank and her father, I think, is a general for the Navy).
The girl also creates a cursed doll which can speak and resembles the MC.


Are you asking about two different manhwa/manhua here? If so, please split this up into two separate questions, otherwise users may vote to close this question for being insufficiently focused.

i cant really remember if its the same or if its a different manhwa so i kept as it is
